# Unable to send file from local to server in node js project using FTP

Tags: javascript, node.js, ftp

I want to upload file from my local machine to server using FTP in node js project.
my project structure-

```
-media
   -one.jpg
   -two.jpg
-node_modules
-views
-index.js
```

my code -

```
client = new ftpClient(config, options);
    client.connect(function () {

        client.upload(['./media/five.png'], 'product', {
            baseDir: 'test',
            overwrite: 'older'
        }, function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        });

    });
```

I am getting this error-
 **Error: The system cannot find the path specified.**

if I am passing full url inspite of `./media/five.png` then I am getting this error-

```
 Error: The parameter is incorrect.
```

how can I send my file to server?

please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned here https://www.npmjs.com/package/ftp-client

baseDir - local base path relative to the remote directory, e.g. if you want to upload file uploads/sample.js to public_html/uploads, baseDir has to be set to uploads

Moreover, your second parameter 'product' should be the path in the destination server
If you want to upload file from your local 'media' directory to remote directory /product/media (assuming the 'product' directory is located at the root of the server) the parameters should look as follow:

```
client = new ftpClient(config, options);
client.connect(function () {

    client.upload(['./media/five.png'], '/product/media', {
        baseDir: 'media',
        overwrite: 'older'
    }, function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    });

});
```

Note: You should use the 'path' node module to join urls and path strings - https://nodejs.org/api/path.html

Comment: i changed as you post above.but still getting same error   Error: The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: client.upload(['five.png'], 'product', ---- this line is working for me...when i put five.png on same level with index.js.

Comment: if i am using client.upload(['media/**'], '/product/media',  then it is also uploading full folder. but it is not working in case of single file